# What happens to an Animagus's old clothes?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, animagi

In both media, when Animagi transform from beast to human, they are fully clothed. In the Prisoner of Azkaban film, we see Wormtail leave his clothes behind, as he transforms into a rat. What happened to them?

Comment: Note: this question applies only to the movies.

Comment: When he turned back into a human, he was fully clothed, presumably in the same garments as when he was transformed

Comment: So, his garments are teleported to his body?

Comment: By magic, as it were. Note that Prof. McGonagoll's glasses form eye rings on her fur.

Comment: I always assumed that Mrs. McGonagoll ended up naked in front of the class in that book (don't remember which one, I believe 2) which is also why she was surprised that nobody in her class applauded her transformation. I also always thought that Peter was naked in the shack at the end of book 3 because it's just way funnier. Mages already have a different relationship to clothes and like air and space around their private parts (4th book).

Comment: @Raditz_35 I don't think you are right but next time I read the books... I need to make that assumption. It sounds like a very funny change.

Comment: @Valorum, similarly: Rita Skeeter's animagus has markings around her antennae, which are exactly like her glasses

Comment: I think having a naked Timothy Spall materialise during the finale may have affected the age rating and the Harry Potter films' reputation as kids movies.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139828/68872) seems to detail exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pettigrew left his clothes behind. Maybe because of the stressing situation but it's also possible to transform the clothing into the animagus form. It depends on the wizards intentions and skills as described in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139828/90947) to a similar question.